Dependency injection vs instantiating using new
I basically want to know the major difference between using constructor dependency injection and instantiating the object in the constructor.
For example:
// Creating instance in the constructor
public Class MyService
{
    private Foo _foo;
    
    MyService()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
    }
}


// Injecting in the constructor
public Class MyService
{
     private Foo _foo;
   
     MyService(Foo _foo)
     {
          _foo = _foo;
     }
}

Now as far as I have read articles/blogs it says in the above code snippet there is tight coupling and in the DI version there is low coupling, now I know the concept of copuling but I am not able to grasp the examples that are provided.
One more difference that I think of is the Lifecycle difference...
But I need someone to clarify it to me. Also if I don't use interfaces while DI, do I really get the benefits of Dependency Injection?

"But I need someone to clarify it to me"  - clarify what?

"but I am not able to grasp the examples that are provided" - examples for / against what?

What if Foo itself needs dependency that you don't know here? How do you easily exchange Foo against something else for example in a Unittest or a more configurable system that needs slightly different behavior? If you think you don't need all of that and think you never need it (ignoring maintenance etc) then consider both examples equal.

"Also if I don't use interfaces while DI, do I really get the benefits of Dependency Injection?" - Mocking Frameworks still can inject a mocked instance for (unit) tests. But that's only one aspect of using DI.

The real principle you ask about is Inversion of Control, not DI. Dependency Injection is a technique used to achieve inversion of control, and quite often refers to the tools used to make IoC easier.

I disagree with the downvotes and can actually understand why there's such confusion. A lot of blog posts and ... lazy authors, confuse the terms or try to push acronyms as part of some methodology, trademarked "architecture" or "best practices".

if I don't use interfaces while DI, do I really get the benefits of Dependency Injection? yes, or rather, the benefits of IoC. Your Foo may be a configuration object or a parameter object for example. You can construct this outside your main classes, eg during application startup, and pass it to them. This way the classes don't have to know how to read settings. In functional-style programming you can pass a Func<T> as a parameter instead of a class. In that case your classes won't have to know anything about Foo, just that you can call it and get what you need

@PanagiotisKanavos I think its good to make the example even more complex with Func, then he can easier understand what Inversion of control means. Hmm...you may be right, but it will not help in understanding it.

There is a set of rules in programming called SOLID. If you follow these rules your code might be better testable, maintainable and better expandability.
And the D in SOLID stands for Dependency Inversion Principle. In short:

Its better to control all your dependencies from outside your class, because when you generate it inside your class you cannot change it (for unit testing or just use another implementation)
Then its easier (or just even possible) to write unit tests
When using an interface you can change the implementation which will be injected into your class without any code change in it

Summary:

Always use Depenency Inversion for better unit tests with an Interface
instead of an concrete class for better expandability. So both of your samples above are somehow bad, because the first uses no Depenency Inversion and the second uses no interfaces.

Finally, how should it looks like with .NET 8.0 and primary constructors:
public class MyService(IFoo foo)
{
     void SomeMethod()
     {
          // use the dependency
          foo.DoSomething();
     }
}


The answer is wrong. Dependency injection isn't used because of some acronyms (which are actually guidelines). The real principle is Inversion of Control - allowing something outside your code to provide the implementation. That means using interfaces or abstract classes, or just a common base class as parameters. It doesn't require a DI framework. Nor does the lack of DI or IoC mean you can't have tests. If, and only if, you use IoC, a DI framework can make life easier.

I didn´t write that he should use it, because of acronyms. Inversion of Control and Dependency Inversion are synonyms. Also I didn´t say that he has to use an DI framework. But of course everybody uses an DI framework. So what is the point?

Inversion of Control is the principle. Dependency Injection is just one technique used to achieve it, and not the cleanest. Functional languages (which includes Javascript) achieve IoC by passing functions around instead of classes.

Inversion of Control and Dependency Inversion are not  synonyms. "But of course everybody uses a DI framework" - no, that's not required and many people try to apply Pure DI. I recommed the book "Dependency Injection - Principles, Practices, and Patterns" by Steven van Deursen and Mark Seemann, where these things are explained in great detail with many practical examples.

@PanagiotisKanavos But the question is about C#. If it would be F# or JavaScript my answer would be different. And I don´t think that for the questioner the difference between Inversion of Control and DI matters here on the level he is.

@Julian Thx. During my time at microsoft, I think I learned what is the difference. but that wasn´t the question and I think it doesn´t help the questioner in his journey to understand it.

Fair points. While I agree that this isn't a beginner topic, I still think reading the book would help anyone new to DI, DIP and IoC.

Yes, we can agree on that. But you recommended the book to me, but I think I don´t need it anymore :) I try to pick up the questioners from where they stand and thats why I wouldn´t start with the most complex examples from other languages and so on. :)
